# My URLs have this "?locale=en" appended. Is that normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have got most of my site working under locales(i18n). However, now I am working on the admin side. And this does not work under any local. I just realized that every URL that is not under the scope of a local has this "?locale=en" appended to the end of the URL.

You can have a look at this site. Every URL seems fine. But, if you go to the top left icon that takes you back to root has that bit added to the URL.
http://hik-fyp.heroku.com

I guess it is to display the root in a certain language. However, when it comes to admin section(which is monolingual) it shows everywhere.

Is it normal? Could this interfere somehow with the site? Is there a way to get rid of it?
I spent a while researching on the net but could not find anything similar. Thanks in advance...

This is a extract from ApplicationController

```
after_filter :store_location
  before_filter :set_locale




  def set_locale
    logger.debug "* Accept-Language: #{request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}"
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
    logger.debug "* Locale set to '#{I18n.locale}'"
    if current_user
      current_user.locale = params[:locale]
      current_user.save
    end
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale
  end


  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end


  def store_location
    # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining that to happen when you set

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

This tells the rails url_for helper (which underlies link_to and many others) to automatically include the locale parameter.